# ios7 UINavigationBar stops extending under status bar after a while

Tags: iphone, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, statusbar

First of all - this is NOT a question about navigation bar overlapping status bar (as many others). 
UINavigationBar (of my navigation controller) is perfectly aligned as I want.

The problem is with my navigation bar custom background.
Background image (or navigation bar itself) stops expending under status bar randomly (after few seconds after my application starts or when I present / dismiss modal navigation controllers over it).
My custom image has proper dimensions for iOS (640x128px).

**1. Initial look (desired - custom 640x128px background extends nicely under status bar):**

[image]

**2. After a while (flickers by itself):**

[image]

What could cause such random flickering of UINavigationBar background image?

I use following code to configure my background:

```
    // Load resources for iOS 7 or later
    [[CustomNavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[self imageNamed:@"bg_top_ios7.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[CustomNavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[self imageNamed:@"bg_top_ios7.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefaultPrompt];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];
```

My status bar settings in the Info.plist file:

[image]

I have also following settings in my UIViewController subclass init method (not sure if it matters):

```
-(id)init{
//DLog(@"BaseViewController init...");
    if (self = [super init]) {

        popToRoot = modal = NO;
        rootIndex = 0;
        indexInBottomNavigation = 0;
        [Crashlytics setObjectValue:@"init" forKey:NSStringFromClass([self class])];


        // iOS 7 adoptions:
        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
            self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars)])
            self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;

        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets)])
            self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;


    }
    return self;
}
```

My view controllers are embedded in UINavigationController (which takes care of UINavigatioBbar positioning). 
I am also using ECSlidingViewController (reveal container) as a container for my navigation controllers but I am not sure if it matters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turned out I was changing `clipsToBounds = YES` of navigation controller's navigation bar (somewhere in the app):

`navigationController.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = YES;`

In order for `UINavigationBar` to extend its background under status bar 
**its clipsToBounds must be set to NO** (which is the default).
Make sure you do not mock around with it.

Solution simple as:

`navigationController.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = NO;`