# Status Bar iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, statusbar

I have two views and I need one to be able to show a white status bar and the other to show no status bar. I have successfully made it show NO status bar but have not been able to have the Main view have a White status bar. I have to use `View controller-based status bar appearance = YES` because otherwise When i go back from the "no status bar view" it makes it makes the whole app have no status bar. Why won't the status bar be white!?!

Current Code for dismising status bar:

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}


-(void)ViewDidLoad {

        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)])
        {
            [self prefersStatusBarHidden];
            [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
        }
        else
        {
            // iOS 6
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
        }
    }
```

Current Code for trying to make the status bar white:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];

    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];

}

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Comment: Do you ever do `setStatusBarHidden:NO` or `prefersStatusBarHidden NO`?

Comment: `View controller-based status bar appearance = NO` Do you mean when I use this? @michaels

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't be calling prefersStatusBarHidden in your first block, you should be implementing it to return true.
2. Make sure you have View controller based status bar appearance (UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance) set to yes in your Info.plist file.

What this all means is that in the VC where you want the status bar hidden you need to put:

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return true;
}

-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
}
```

In the other VC, put:

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return false;
}

-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Just checked it out and it all seems to work as expected.  Note that in iOS 7, UIStatusBarStyle only controls the color of the text in the status bar, the background color is determined by the navigation bar itself.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The view won't dismiss status bar without `prefersStatusBarHidden`

Comment: I do have `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` set to yes, but the status bar does not turn white with it to yes. @David

Comment: The other thing to note is that with iOS 7, the status bar background is established by the navigation bar.  The UIStatusBarStyle determines the text color.

Comment: So how would i make it white? In the storyboard? @David

Comment: Are you using a nav bar?

Comment: You also shouldn't need to call setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate unless the value to be returned by your prefersStatusBarHidden method changes.  UINavigationController will handle that under normal circumstances.

Comment: Yes I'm using a NavBar. I do call  `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];`

Comment: I call it in the view I need the white status bar.

Comment: I see that you are, you shouldn't need to if all of this happens with normal UINavigationController operations.

Comment: You should also be probably doing all of this in viewDid/WillAppear instead of viewDidLoad.

Comment: Yes I'm hiding then showing. But from launch i don't have the White status bar

Comment: With your edited code the status bar just wants to stay white. (Note: `View controller-based status bar appearance is set to YES`)

Comment: self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

Add this to the ViewDidLoad and you get what you need... A white bar.

Answer (score 0):

> Why won't the status bar be white!?!

Well, simply because it is transparent. The "background colour" of the status bar is now (post ios7) the colour of the view/window *behind* the status bar.

> but have not been able to have the Main view have a White status bar

The solution I commonly use, is to force the navigationController's navigationBar to render *below* the status bar rather than *behind* it. This way, the navigationBar's colour/background image doesn't extend under the status bar and the status bar's "background colour" is now the colour of the window.

To force the navigation bar to start *below* the status bar, you set its clipsToBounds property to YES.

```
_navigationController.navigationBar.clipsToBounds   = YES;
```

To set the background colour of the window,

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Ref: [Ironically, our "solution" was someone else's "bug" :)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21018401/1349663)